# Export logs using Pagination n LogDNA

Tags: pagination, ibm-cloud, logdna

I am referring to the [link](https://docs.logdna.com/docs/export-lines) for exporting logs.

As mentioned in this link, I want to understand how to programmatically support pagination for exported logs. We have a requirement where we have to export logs based on a filter which could go over the limit mentioned.
Could you please share the details of the same and sample code that i can refer to.

I had some queries regarding the export of logs to emails.

1. Is there any other way of exporting/downloading the logs without sending to a particular email ID.
2. If the person who receives email for exported logs doesn't have access to LogDNA, how the person can access the logs.
   Thanks.